# Word or phrase that describes talks, sessions, posters, etc. at a conference

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word (or maybe two words) that describe the following type of presentations:

- Talks at conferences
- Poster sessions at conferences

Context: In my CV, I would like to create a heading under which I present all talks and poster sessions I have presented in past technical and academic conferences. I am trying to figure what is the best possible heading for such a section.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a single word, I would suggest a heading of either ***Lectures*** or perhaps ***Presentations***.  If you're okay with more than one word, I would combine them as ***Lectures and Presentations***.

From the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[lecture](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lecture)***
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. An educational talk to an audience, especially one of students in a university.
>
>    *‘in each course there are supporting lectures and tutorials’*

and

> ***[presentation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/presentation)***
>
> **noun**
>
> 2. A speech or talk in which a new product, idea, or piece of work is shown and explained to an audience.
>
>    *‘a sales presentation’*

You could also use ***Lectures and Posters***, if that would be understood to be referring to the posters used in *[poster sessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poster_session)* (which, I'll admit, I had to look up).

I'm not sure there's a single word that would cover both Lectures/Talks and Posters, other than, perhaps, *presentations*.

Answer (score 0):

**exhibits**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/exhibit)

> someone who organizes an exhibit for others to see

As in:

> In my CV, I have created the heading **Exhibits** under which I
>   present all talks and poster sessions I have presented in past
>   technical and academic conferences.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of English, the most appropriate term is *presentation*. You are presenting either way, whether as a oral presentation or as a poster session. In the context of an academic CV you could also use *conference participation* or *research outputs* (including publications). It may be worth distinguishing publications that have been peer-reviewed, that you were first or last author on, and presentations that you presented (rather than co-authored).

It’s your CV so it’s up to you if they haven’t provided a template or requested a particular format. Usually, you can organise it any way you like but try to make sure this information, that they will look for can be found easily. Bear in mind that if there are many applications, they will not spend long looking for this key information.